# How do i execute a sh in a different directory?

Tags: bash

Hello im bored of typing the same two code everytime when i start up my terminal. And im trying to
execute these two commands in one sh file! Im new to this stuff so i tried to make these 2 codes in one sh file. i looked up many people saying codes that will work but they wont work for me. Can anybody help me?

```
cd /home/justphil/braddey
```

```
java -jar server.jar nogui
```

Comment: Is `server.jar` under `/home/justphil/braddey`?  Does `java -jar /home/justphil/braddey/server.jar nogui` not work?

Comment: @Nmath make it an answer and Ill remove my part ;)

Comment: @Nmath sever.jar is in /home/justphil/braddey´. and java -jar /home/justphil/braddey/server.jar nogui wont work. But i found a answer to my question now :)

Comment: I keep my own scripts in `/usr/local/bin/`  (okay the script will still be in a local or network directory; but I put a link there as that directory is in the default $PATH (where commands are searched))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods to do what you want. Just 2 others are likely to add more:

- Put this in a script and make it executable with `chmod 700 {file}`:

  ```
  cd /home/justphil/braddey && java -jar server.jar nogui && cd ~-
  ```

  The last part changes back to the directory you started it in.
- Change `server.jar` to `/home/justphil/braddey`

Comment: Thank you! It worked. And the server.jar was in in /home/justphil/braddey.